# How to work with Nullable<T> types in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

In Powershell, variables are nullable by default. So it makes sense that if I define a variable with a `Nullable<T>` type, Powershell detects this and actually creates a variable of the underlying type `T`.

```
PS>[System.Nullable[System.Int32]]$foo = 0  
PS>$foo.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

The problem is that this fails when `$null`is involved.

```
PS>[System.Nullable[System.Int32]]$foo = $null
PS>$foo.GetType()
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior and keep the original `Nullable` type?

Comment: PowerShell and nullables mix poorly. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, though: `.GetType()` always lies for nullables, not just in PowerShell, so `.GetType()` is not legal on any null-valued nullable -- this is [true in C# as well](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwJZWAfgASuwXmyggBsSBuAWACgABARgDoGBOAClUYHEBTYAFQCeABx5sAlOKrUgA==). But while C# has ways of detecting nullables through generic type parameters, PowerShell does not. You *do* get a real nullable this way, as proven by the fact that `[int] $foo` cannot be set to `$null` -- you get `0` instead.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are right. I hadn't realised that C# didn't allow this either. I was thinking about using [Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype?view=net-5.0) until I realized that it takes a Type parameter, not an actual Nullable. So I would still have to call $null.GetType() (NRE). Guess I will have to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

I've not found any way to retrieve the original type.

Nullable types are more or less only useful to prevent implicit null coalescing or conversion to a default value, such as `[int]$foo = $null` results in a value of `0` for `$foo`. However, nullable types don't expose their boxing at all to allow retrieval of the originally declared type:

```
> [System.Nullable[System.Int32]]$foo = 0
> $foo -is [System.Nullable[System.Int32]]
False
> $foo -is [System.Int32]
True
> [System.Nullable[System.Int32]]$foo = $null
> $foo -is [System.Nullable[System.Int32]]
False
> $null -eq $foo
True
```

So, you will still need to treat the value of the variable itself as a more-or-less raw `$null` and test it with `$null -eq $foo` or use manual null coalescing with `$foo ?? $replacementValue` or similar.

I've only ever found a use for them as a type declaration for mandatory function or cmdlet parameters where the input might legitimately be `$null` and I need to preserve that, which is fairly rare.

Often, the easiest workaround is to use a collection such as a HashTable, PSCustomObject, or class with named properties that could be nullable, but your program needs to know about the data types without using introspection methods like `.GetType()`, `Get-Member`, or `-is`. Another alternative would be to use a DataTable, where columns have fixed data types but allow `$null` values.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is just another PowerShell gotcha, similar to

```
[string]$foo = $null; $null -eq $foo; '' -eq $foo
False
True
```

You can check `CimConverter` in [the PowerShell code base](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/cimSupport/cmdletization/cim/cimConverter.cs).